# Remote Desktop 2012 R2 performance lacks when multiple sessions are open

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, hypervisor

We have a performance issue on our Virtual Windows 2012 R2 server that is configured as a Remote Desktop Server. Also a customer of us, that uses our software, is facing the same problem on a 2012 R2 server connecting using RDC.

For testing we wrote a small app that calculates some prime numbers and measures time to check the performance.

The server itself is powerful (Intel Xeon E5, 2.4ghz - 64GB of RAM). The Server is configured in a domain and has the Remote Desktop feature installed.

Tests done:

- Virtual Windows 2008 Server => no performance issues
- virtual Windows 10 installation => no performance issues
- Connection using Remote Desktop Client is fast
- We changed the Fairshare values, no change

Findings:

- The performance is good when connecting using Hyper-V **until** there is one Remote Desktop user connected to the server. As soon as one RD-user is connected, the performance starts to lack.
- The performance lacks even more when two or three RD-users are connected.
  We configured several settings (1, 2, 4, 8, 16 processor usage of the virtual machine, Fairshare on/off) but nothing really improved the performance (of course, with parallel execution and only 1 processor it takes naturally longer than execution on 2 processors)

Does anyone has an idea what we could check & test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out, that the Hypervisor Server was configured to use a balanced-power setting. After changing we see that all the virtual Servers have increased performance.

We also excluded the vhdx files from being checked by the antivirus on the Hypervisor Server.

Yet not completely sure if this also solves our customers problems but we made a step ahead.

Here is the solution: [Best practice to disable SpeedStep for Hyper-V hosts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/661209/best-practice-to-disable-speedstep-for-hyper-v-hosts)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an idea of  what happening on your server, you can use the Performance Analyser of Windows 2012. You can launch a record during 24h of all counters and with that, you will be able to see where come from your performance problem. It could be the processsors, the memory, the disks or one process.

Be carefull, the report files generated by the analyser performances can be very big, think to split them during the analyse.

Comment: Thanks. We were already analysing performance using the Performance Analyser but it did not lead us there. Please see my other comment